# How to evaluate the continued fraction $[1,2,3,1,4,1,4,1,4\dots]$

Tags: elementary-number-theory

> How does one evaluate the continued fraction $[1,2,3,1,4,1,4,1,4...]$?

**My attempt**

Take

$$y=[1,4,1,4,1,4\dots]={1+\frac{1}{4+\frac{1}{y}}}$$

so that $$4y^2-4y-1=0\quad\text{and}\quad y=\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}$$

which becomes

$$x=1+2+3+\frac{1}{y}=6+\frac{\left(1+\sqrt{2}\right)}{2}=4+2\sqrt{2}$$

Is this right?

Comment: Close. Something that should raise a red flag: isn't $1+2+3$ strange? Why not just write $[6, \ldots]$ instead of $[1,2,3,\ldots]$? Related to that, the first entry of a continued fraction should be followed by a semicolon: $[a_0; a_1, a_2, a_3, \ldots]$. (Why?)

Comment: @Théophile $[1,2,3]=6$?? $[1,2,3]=1+1/(2+1/3)=10/7$.

Comment: @Chrystomath I didn't claim that $[1,2,3] = 6$, the OP did. That's my point.

Comment: @Théophile I know, but it reinforced the asker's statement.

Comment: @Chrystomath Reinforced it? I'm saying that it should raise a red flag. There's clearly something wrong.

Comment: @Théophile, I agree that the $1+2+3$ is inappropriate, but there are other problems as well. Even if you allow $x=1+2+3+{1\over y}$, the final two equalities are wrong:  $1/y\not=(1+\sqrt2)/2$, and $6+(1+\sqrt2)/2\not=4+2\sqrt2$.

Comment: To be more explicit: $1+2+3$ is wrong. If it worked like that, then what would be the difference between $[1,2,3,\ldots]$ or $[6,\ldots]$ or $[1,5,\ldots]$ or $[1,1,1,1,1,1,\ldots]$, etc.? And how would you know how many terms to include in this initial sum? Instead, each new term creates a new fraction within the old one: $[1; 2, 3, \ldots] = 1 + \frac1{2 + \frac1{3 + \ldots}}$.

Comment: @BarryCipra Yes, I realize that also, but I was addressing what I felt was the most critical misunderstanding.

Comment: @Théophile, very well. I misinterpreted what you meant by "Close."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have correctly found the value of $y = [1;4,1,4,1,4,\cdots]$ (Noting that I have used a semicolon after the first $1$ and not a comma). To finish, you just need to note that

\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{rcl}
[1;2,3,1,4,1,4,1,4\cdots] & = & 1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{[1;4,1,4,1,4,\cdots]}}}\\
& = & 1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{1}{\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{2}}}}\\
& = & 1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1}{3+\frac{2}{1+\sqrt{2}}}}\\
& = & 1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{3(1+\sqrt{2})+2}}\\
& = & 1+\frac{1}{2+\frac{1+\sqrt{2}}{5+3\sqrt{2}}}\\
& = & 1+\frac{5+3\sqrt{2}}{2(5+3\sqrt{2})+1+\sqrt{2}}\\
& = & 1+\frac{5+3\sqrt{2}}{11+7\sqrt{2}}\\
& = & \boxed{\frac{16+10\sqrt{2}}{11+7\sqrt{2}}}\\
\end{array}
\end{equation}